# Build an android apk from Unity3d project working with C/C++ dll

Tags: android, dll, unity-game-engine

I made a Unity3d project working with C/C++ Dll.
So first I made the dll in Visual studio.

```
// mydll.cpp
#define EXPORT_API __declspec(dllexport)
extern "C" {
    int EXPORT_API add(int a, int b)
    {
        return a+b;
    }
}
```

And I added this dll into my Unity3D project and called

```
// C# script in Unity3D
public class TestDll : MonoBehaviour {
    [DllImport("mydll")]
    private static extern int add (int a, int b);

    void Start() {
        int a = add (100, 200);
    }
}
```

This code works well and I got the correct result in Unity3D editor.

So I built this project to android platform and got an apk.
I installed and run this apk on my android device but the app doesn't work.
The app didn't run the Dll function.

Whats the matter? I tried to find out the solution in Google and here, but didn't get anything, yet.
Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: android/ios can't use dlls

Comment: So in this case what shall I do? Anyway I want to reuse the current C/C++ based library. Can I make this library module into .so or other file format, so android app can use it?

Comment: Unity generates an Xcode project (probably something similar for Android too). You have to add the C/C++ code to that project and compile it for the target platform using the platform-specific compilers. Visual Studio will not generate iOS/Android or any ARM compatible code for that matter to begin with, and at least iOS can't load dynamic libraries, and specifically not DLLs (that's a library format only available on desktop/x86 platforms if I'm correctly informed).

Answer (score 0):

Your dll must be in Plugins folder for Windows, it can work for Editor too. for Android you must replace in Plugins/Android folder. Build and write me ok

Answer (score 0):

LearnCocos2D's comment is accurate.

To get Unity to DllImport() a shared library on Android, you must use an NDK compiler and specify a compile config for your target Android platform. Moreover, Unity requires you to specify the architecture of the Android platform in the build settings, eg.. "arm v7" vs "arm64".
As an aside, in Unity 2019.4 - selecting "Load on Startup" in the inspector page of my .so elicits a "DLLNotFoundException".

Overview of this: https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.4/Documentation/Manual/AndroidNativePlugins.html

NDK's CMake guide for getting you started on compiling correctly: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cmake